# where to specify redirect uri for openID connect in cordova ionic native app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, openid-connect

I am using inappbrowser to get the Auth token from the provider. And the redirect uri given is like **myapp://authorize**. After successful login, it does not redirect back to the application.
I dont understand how to specify the redirect uri in cordova native app.

```
this.openIDUrl = this.iab.create(urlRequest, '_blank', iabConfig);
        return Observable.combineLatest(
          this.openIDUrl.on('exit').map((event: any) => {
            Observable.of({ 'error': 'openIdAuthError.browserClose' });
          }),
          this.openIDUrl.on('loadstart').flatMap((event: any) => {
            alert('after loadstart: ' + event.url);
            if (event.url.indexOf('AccessToken') > -1) {
              alert('something');
            });
);
```

The window.location gives **android_asset/www/index.html**. May be I need to create some custom url in ionic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin cordova-customurlscheme.  With it you provide a callback function which will get called when your defined URL is opened on your device.  So if you enter your myapp://authorize URL in the browser or elsewhere on your device, it will redirect to your cordova/iconic app.